# Cant able to access Whatsapp Manager in Faceebook Business Manager

Tags: facebook, api, whatsapp

Trying Whatsapp API integration , followed the steps mentioned in https://www.facebook.com/business/help/2087193751603668 but cant see whatsapp account creation option in Business Manager.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNGEc.jpg)

Please tell us how to achieve

Comment: Hello, and welcome on SO! take a look on [ask]. For example, links, images and links to images are discouraged: in the future it won't be possible to understand what you're asking if the link goes down, and images can be a problem for who is browsing from mobile

Comment: There is a notice right on top of the documentation you linked to, saying _“This feature is gradually rolling out and may not be available to you right now.”_

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading Whatsapp for business on a mobile, configure it on your mobile, then add it to facebook in the page you provided.